# Bind Entity with KeyValuePair to Datagrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Below is my class with Keyvalue pair

```
public class GridExpression
{
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public KeyValuePair<string, double> T1 { get; set; }
    public KeyValuePair<string, double> T2 { get; set; }
    public KeyValuePair<string, double> T3 { get; set; }


}
ObservableCollection<GridExpression> grid = new 
ObservableCollection<GridExpression>();
```

I want to bind the above ObservableCollection to a Datagrid

also if we use List instead if Keypairvalue

like Below XAML Code, I have added 2 T1 one with Grid and another with `Wrappanel`
grid show at least aqua color of the Textblock background

```
<DataGrid x:Name="_timeframe_Copy" Margin="0,408.152,10,10" AlternatingRowBackground="#FFFFF5D4" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="766.167">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Count" Binding="{Binding Count}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" Binding="{Binding Title}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="T1">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="T1" MinWidth="10">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid x:Name="brdBroder" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="1" DataContext="{Binding T1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Margin="3,1" Background="Aqua" Foreground="White" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" Margin="3,1" />
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="T1" MinWidth="10">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <WrapPanel x:Name="brdBroder" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="1" DataContext="{Binding T1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Margin="3,1" Background="Aqua" Foreground="White" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" Margin="3,1" />
                            </WrapPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="T2" MinWidth="10">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <WrapPanel x:Name="brdBroder" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="1" DataContext="{Binding T2, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Margin="3,1" Background="Aqua" Foreground="White" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" Margin="3,1" />
                            </WrapPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="T3" MinWidth="10">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <WrapPanel x:Name="brdBroder" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="1" DataContext="{Binding T2, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Margin="3,1" Background="Aqua" Foreground="White" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" Margin="3,1" />
                            </WrapPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I don't know how to bind Key-value pairs and the binding to *Datagridtemplate*

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `DataContext` Binding.

The `DataContext` of the `DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate` is `GridExpression`.

That why you only neet to change this line:

```
<WrapPanel x:Name="brdBroder" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="1" DataContext="{Binding T1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}">
```

to:

```
<WrapPanel x:Name="brdBroder" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="1" DataContext="{Binding T1}">
```